# Redis - How to expire key daily

Tags: node.js, unix, redis, timestamp, sails.js

I know that EXPIREAT in Redis is used to specify when a key will expire. My problem though is that it takes an absolute UNIX timestamp. I'm finding a hard time thinking about what I should set as an argument if I want the key to expire at the end of the day.

This is how I set my key:

> client.set(key, body);

So to set the expire at:

> client.expireat(key, ???);

Any ideas? I'm using this with nodejs and sailsjs 
Thanks!

Comment: which redis npm  module you are using ,is that all redis npm module support expireat() function. ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you want to expire it 24 hrs later

```
client.expireat(key, parseInt((+new Date)/1000) + 86400);
```

Or if you want it to expire exactly at the end of today, you can use [`.setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) on a `new Date()` object to get the time at the end of the day, and use that.

```
var todayEnd = new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
client.expireat(key, parseInt(todayEnd/1000));
```

Comment: where is it documented?

Comment: I did not manage to find this anywhere documented? How did you find this?

Comment: Is expiresat sync or async? I have a lot of questions

Comment: @laggingreflex is the `+` sign in front of `new Date` really required?

Comment: How to set expiration never in redis ?

Comment: How about Date.now() instead of +new Date/1000?

Comment: Here is the Node Docs: https://redis.js.org/#node-redis-usage-redis-commands

Answer (score 36):

Since **SETNX, SETEX, PSETEX** are going to be deprecated in the next releases, the correct way is:

```
client.set(key, value, 'EX', 60 * 60 * 24, callback);
```

See [here](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/1000) for a detailed discussion on the above.

Answer (score 25):

For new version `^4.6.7`, you have can use set and expire like

```
await client.set(key , value, {EX: 60*60*24})
```

`EX` should be set in seconds (eg: 60 * 60 * 24 seconds = 1 day)

Comment: This is the correct way at least for versions `^4.6.7`

Comment: yes, also for me this worked but the other options did not

Comment: This is the one that works for the latest version of redis-npm.

Docs: https://redis.js.org/#node-redis-usage-redis-commands

Answer (score 18):

You can set value and expiry together.

```
  //here key will expire after 24 hours
  client.setex(key, 24*60*60, value, function(err, result) {
    //check for success/failure here
  });

 //here key will expire at end of the day
  client.setex(key, parseInt((new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999)-new Date())/1000), value, function(err, result) {
    //check for success/failure here
  });
```

Comment: its work but better to ignore this command .. because in redis document :" **_Note: Since the SET command options can replace SETNX, SETEX, PSETEX, it is possible that in future versions of Redis these three commands will be deprecated and finally removed._** "   [redis set command](https://redis.io/commands/set)